# Solving Binomial probability question- what's wrong with my solution?

Tags: probability, statistics, solution-verification, binomial-distribution

> A company establishes a fund of $120$ from which it wants to pay an amount, $C$, to any of its $20$ employees who achieve a high-performance level during the coming year. each employee has a $2\%$ chance of achieving a high-performance level during the coming year, independent of any other employees. Determine the maximum value of $C$ for which the probability is less than $1\%$ that the fund will be inadequate to cover all payments for high performance.
>
> Multiple-Choice Options: $24, 30, 40, 60, 120$.

**My attempt:**

Let $X$ be the RV denoting the number of employees that need to be paid the amount $C$. $X \sim Bin(20, 0.02)$. We need to find $P(X>120/C)<0.01$.

Note that $P(X= 0) = 0.667$, $P(X= 1) = 0.272$, $P(X= 2) = 0.052$, $P(X= 3) = 0.006$. Since $P(X= 3)<0.01$, we obtain $$3>\frac{120}{C} \implies C>40$$

I chose the option for $40$, however, the correct answer is $60$. Now, since my answer said $C>40$, I should have chosen $60$ or $120$, but I suspect that the solution has major flaws. Can someone please review my solution and let me know where I went wrong? Thanks.

Comment: Formatting tip:  To obtain $\%$ when you are in math mode, type `$\%$`.

Comment: If $C=60$ then the fund is inadequate iff there are  three or more high performers.  Easy to verify that $P(X≥3)<.01$

Comment: @lulu Could you please explain why you're considering "three or more high performers" instead of something like exactly three high performers or exactly 4 high performers?

Comment: The fund is inadequate if too many people qualify. If $C=60$ then we can pay $0,1$ or $2$ people.  If there are $3,4,5,$ and so on, the fund is inadequate.

Comment: In this case the probabilities drop so fast that the distinction scarcely matters,  I get $P(X=3)=0.006469015$ while $P(X≥3)=0.007068693$  but, in general, one should work with the latter instead of the former.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fund will be insufficient if $X$ is "too large."  We want to limit the probability of this.  This suggests finding some integer $c$ such that $$\Pr[X > c] < 0.01. \tag{1}$$ Since $X \sim \operatorname{Binomial}(n = 20, p = 0.02)$, we calculate a table:
$$\begin{array}{c|c|c|c}
x & \Pr[X = x] & \Pr[X \le x] & \Pr[X > x] \\
\hline
0 & 0.667608 & 0.667608 & 0.332392 \\
1 & 0.272493 & 0.940101 & 0.059899 \\
2 & 0.0528303 & 0.992931 & 0.00706869 \\
3 & 0.00646901 & 0.9994 & 0.000599679
\end{array}$$
The third column is computed by successively adding up entries in the second column, and the fourth column is $1$ minus the third column.  We observe that the first value of $x$ for which the desired inequality $(1)$ is satisfied is $x = 2$; therefore, this is our value of $c$.  Hence the probability of having more than $2$ high-performing employees is less than $0.01$, and if the award is $C$, the company can make $C = 60$ without having the probability of insufficient funds exceed $0.01$, since the probability of three or more high-performing employees is less than $0.01$.

---

Your error is in concluding $c = 3$ rather than $c = 2$.  But there is a more fundamental error, which is that you did not compute *cumulative* probabilities.  Instead, you computed *individual* probabilities and stopped when $\Pr[X = c] < 0.01$.  This is not correct, as the inequality $(1)$ above explains.

Answer (score 0):

From your  $P(X= 0) = 0.668$, $P(X= 1) = 0.272$, $P(X= 2) = 0.053$, $P(X= 3) = 0.006$ (with slightly better rounding)

you can find $P(X> 0) = 0.332$, $P(X> 1) = 0.060$, $P(X> 2) = 0.007$, $P(X> 3) = 0.001$.

So there is a probability of less than $1\%$ that there are more than $2$ high-performers, but more than $1\%$ that there is more than $1$ high-performer,

and thus you need the fund of $120$ to be able to pay out to up to two high performers at a potential cost of $2C$.

$2C \le 120$ implies $C \le 60$.